# How to load input files to postman collections triggered via GitHub Action Workflows

Tags: postman, github-actions, multipartform-data

How to load input files to postman collections triggered via GitHub Action Workflows.

Pass file input location from local file system (say git repo containing test data)

1. as raw body in request to server
2. as multi-part text file input in request to server

We can't have static references in file system, while running as a GitHub action. How to circumvent and pass the inputs correctly

> ```
>  - name: Run API Tests
>     id: run-newman
>     run: newman run postman/foo.postman_collection.json -r cli --color on -e postman/${{ needs.build.outputs.tenant_name }}.postman_environment.json
> ```

One of the test cases fails like this since it wouldn't find the file which is being referenced in the collection, hence it needs to be loaded from the git repo. I am not sure how to do that

```
→ Upload Image
  ┌
  │ 'Form param `file`, file load error: "/Users/user/Downloads/20230823112156.png", no such file'
```

Comment: Could you share the workflow you're using and what implementations you tried in the question?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I have added the test snippet which is being used for running the collection. The issue is not about running the collection, its about how to pass dynamic inputs (say files) which are needed for certain POST calls

Comment: You explained that you `can't have static references in file system`. Could you give more context? Because from what I understand, it would be possible to configure those files statically in the postman collection and create / import / use those files in the runner execution before executing the collection, wouldn't it?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I have given a sample error and a reason why it fails, let me know if its not clear. How to reference files from within postman

Comment: This issue looks similar, https://community.postman.com/t/upload-a-file-while-running-the-collection-you-need-not-mention-any-static-location-file-instead-you-can-upload-the-file-s-from-desired-location/38978

Comment: It seems downloading the file to the expected location for the collection to use did the trick there, right?